# Coefficient matrix in SageMath

Tags: python, matrix, sage, coefficients

I am relatively new to SageMath and to Python. I have lists of objects of the form `(k, A)` with `k` an integer and `A` a symbolic expression (in my case, it is a couple of monomials, but I would like to know the general answer if possible). For example, suppose I have:

```py
l1 = [(2, A1), (1, A3)]
l2 = [(-1, A3), (3, A2)]
```

This is a very minimal example: in the cases I want to consider, I have many lists, each containing dozens of entries. But no list contain two elements with the same second element; for example, there is no list containing `(1, A1)` and `(2, A1)`.

I would like to extract the first component of corresponding symbolic expressions to have a matrix such that each line correspond to a list, and the columns are indexed by the `A1, ..., An` that appears in at least one list. Also, the entry `(i, j)` is the first component of `(k, Aj)` in the list `i` if it appears, and `0` otherwise.

In my example, I would like to have the matrix

```py
[[2, 0, 1], [0, 3, -1]]
```

But I am unable to know how to do in general! I thought it should be like the `f.coefficient_matrix()` of a polynomial `f`, but the strategy of this algorithm distinguishes the elements using exponents, and in my case there are too many possibilities for the possible `A`.

Is there a way to do this anyway?